# Meaning of manor layam

Tags: shloka, translation

Pooja koti samam stotram 
Stotra koti samam japam 
Japa koti samam dhyanam 
Dhyan koti manor layam

What is the meaning of manor layam in the above Shloka ?

Note : On some other sites ***samolayah*** is also used in place of ***manor layam***, which one is correct ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Sloka is found in the 9th Chapter of the KulArnava Tantram.

> PujAkoti-samam stotram stotra-koti-samo japah |
>  Japa-koti-samam
>   dhyAnam dhyAna-koti-samo layah ||
>
> Stotra is equal to a crore of PujA. A Japa is equal to crore of
>   Stotra.  DhyAna is equal to a crore of Japah and one crore of DhyAna
>   is equal to Laya.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 9, Sloka 36**

Here, "Laya" means "dissolution of mind" referring to a Samadhi kind of  state which is achieved at the highest stage of Dhyanam. That's why its stated "dhyAna-koti-samo layah".

The verse is talking about some kind of a hierarchy of some spiritual practices like doing a formal worship, chanting mantras, reciting Stotras etc. And the whole Chapter is dedicated to the topic of Kula-Yoga and Kula-Yogis.

Comment: What is kula yoga? And who are kula yogis? And is this hierarchy of mantra dhyana stotra and laya only applicable to them or also for general people?

Comment: @LSSJBroly Kaulism (Kaula) is sect among Shaktism. Kularnava Tantra is one of the scriptures for this sect. Kula Yogis therefore are Yogis from this Sampradaya similarly for Kula Yoga. No, this verse is generally valid for everyone. There are similar verses in other texts too

Comment: Thanks a lot :D