# What is the source of "Japatho nasthi pathakam"?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, japa

The continuous repetition of sacred words such as god names, mantras, etc. is said to be a Japa.

Japa is so much powerful. It is crore times more powerful than Puja and Stotra. You can read more about the following from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35298/661)

> Stotra is equal to a crore of PujA. A Japa is equal to crore of
> Stotra. DhyAna is equal to a crore of Japah and one crore of DhyAna is
> equal to Laya.

So, it is necessary for a person to do Japa in order to improve herself. I came across the following verse recently saying that *greatest sins can be removed by doing a Japa*.

> **Japatho nasthi pathakam**

But I cannot find the source scripture of the verse. What is the source of this verse?

Answer (score 9):

It seems the phrase "Japato Nasti Patakam" occurs in many places:

#### - Maya Tantra:

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46354/benefits-of-devi-durga-naam-jap-with-proofs-scriptural-reference-from-s%C4%81shtras/48330#48330), 5th patala of Maya Tantra contains Durga Nama Japa Mahima which says:

> दुर्गेति द्व्यक्षरं मन्त्रं **जपतो नास्ति पातकम्‌**॥7॥ 
>  
> Performing the Japa of this two-syllabled Mantra Durga clears all the sins.

### - Lakshmi Narayana Samhita:

[3.130.80](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lakshminarayana-samhita-sanskrit/d/doc605481.html) of Lakshmi Narayana Samhita also contains the phrase:

> मयि न्यस्तसमग्रस्य **जपतो नास्ति पातकम्** । 
> mayi nyastasamagrasya **japato nāsti pātakam** ।

### - Chanakya Neeti:

Chanakya neeti [3.11](https://sanskritshlokas.com/chanakya-niti-shlokas-chapter-3-21-slokas/) also contains the phrase:

> उद्योगे नास्ति दारिद्र्यं **जपतो नास्ति पातकम्** । 
> मौनेन कलहो नास्ति नास्ति जागरिते भयम् ॥ 
>  
> There is no poverty for the industrious. **Sin does not attach itself to the
> person practicing Japa**. Those who are absorbed in Silence (Mauna) have
> no quarrel with others. They are fearless who always remain alert.

Comment: Yeah, I am in search of the most general one that says about Japa in general. Like the last one you quoted.

Answer (score 7):

Ashta Vimshati Vishnu Namastotram (28 names of Vishnu), 4th shloka:

> Anantham Krishna gopalam japatho nasthi pathakam. 4

Comment: Good find.......